# Amazon in-app-purchases how to test payments

Tags: android, flash, in-app-purchase, amazon-pay, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am working with Amazon In-app-purchases for Android on flash using native extentions. So, I have implemented purchase flow in sandbox ( I was using their file InAppSDK-SandboxData.json for debug). But now, I have an amazon account. I have created purchase items in my developers account, and I want to test flow of buying them.

```
String requestId = PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseRequest(product_id);
```

but it throws an exception, it try to open file "InAppSDK-SandboxData.json", but I have deleted in hope that it will go to product servers, but it does not. I found that I can only make purchases when I will commit my app to Amazon app store((

So, how can I test my real payments to product servers and how can I debug this process?? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143033/in-app-payment-in-amazon  please see this link at once

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem that I am able to run in app demo in sandbox mode but not able to run in live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right now, you can't :(**

I've implemented Amazon In-app-purchases for Android in my last project and the only way you have to test is using InAppSDK-SandboxData.json. Once everything works fine then you commit the app to Amazon App Store and they'll debug for you.

My advise, if it's working fine using InAppSDK-SandboxData.json and you can't wait a month or two (I'm sorry but I can't tell you anymore because I'm still under NDA. I'll edit my response soon), you don't be afraid and commit the app. I did it ;)

**UPDATE:**

It's official right now, **you have a test app in the developer site**, you only must use it ;)

Comment: i have a query on that can you please help me?

Comment: @Goofy Ask an I'll try to help you.

Comment: @Venkat I don't know what can be happening to you with this fairly description, sorry, I need more information. Why don't you try opening a new question?. This question was asked 1 year ago...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143033/in-app-payment-in-amazon see this link at once @gergonzalez

Answer (score 0):

Now you can test in-app purchasing using "LiveApp testing" before publishing to customers.

Check this link
https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/live-app-testing/docs/getting-started

Comment: I am getting "an error occurred while processing your purchase". It was working fine SAND BOX. I am using IAP 2.0. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Hope you have already set the in-app purchase item in the developer control. And you should give the correct SKU name in your code too. It is working for me...

Comment: saneesh, Yes it might be problem with SKU. {"com.mycompany.myapp.iap.subscription.yearly":{"price":1.99,"itemType":"SUBSCRIPTION","subscriptionParent":"com.mycompany.myapp.iap.subscription","smallIconUrl":"https:","description":"Yearly subscription to 911Cast","title":"Yearly Subscription"}}

Comment: I am using in MySku.java
    MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS("com.mycompany.myapp.iap.subscription", "US"); is it right ?

Comment: @San , I am also facing the same issue as describe in above comment. Please help me in it. $Gangadhar Nimballi did you resolved your issue?